# Is it possible to charge a battery using a water flow sensor?

Tags: battery

Is it possible to use a water flow sensor to charge a battery? Since the water flow sensor measures water flow using pulses, could I charge a battery using these pulses(instead of using it to read water flow).

Heres an example of the product?
https://netram.co.za/1200-g-12-water-flow-sensor-13mm.html

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to charge a battery using a water flow sensor?

No, it is basically a hall-effect sensor that requires power and generates a low effect pulse.

Look for a generator. Something like this; https://netram.co.za/1199-36v-micro-hydro-generator.html

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much Mikael.  This helps me a great deal!  Especially that you went through the effort on showing me on the site I used.